# No matching function for cv::merge

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to merge 3 monochrome camera image in one 3 channeled opencv matrix. I try this in the following way:

```
    cv::Mat merged;
    std::vector<cv::Mat> channels[3];

    while(1){
        channels[0]=Camera1->getNextFrameSWTrig();  //give back frame_time and frame_num
        channels[1]=Camera2->getNextFrameSWTrig();  //give back frame_time and frame_num
        channels[2]=Camera3->getNextFrameSWTrig();

        cv::merge(channels, merged);

        (*buffer).push_back(merged.clone());

    }
```

But the following error message comes:

> no matching function for call to 'merge'

Altough in the OpenCV documentation I found:

> C++: void merge(InputArrayOfArrays mv, OutputArray dst)

Comment: Have you included `<opencv2/imgproc.hpp>` ?

Comment: Also `std::vector<cv::Mat> channels[3];` should be `std::vector<cv::Mat> channels(3);` You want a vector with 3 elements, not 3 vectors

Comment: @Miki this resolved the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> channels[3];
                             ^ ^
```

you're creating an array of 3 `std::vector`, while you want a `std::vector` with 3 elements:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> channels(3);
                             ^ ^
```

Comment: you're creating an array of vectors, same as `int a[3];` is an array of 3 integers